# Can't get the background color for fill in the proper section in my page (HTML/ CSS)

Tags: html, css, background-color

Hi im having a problem with my html and css code. Im trying to put all the contents center aligned in the browser whenever, it is resized, but keep the background color to flow continuously horizontally.
I have the following codes but seems that the background color is overlapping some sections in my page. What did I missed or incorrectly done? Thanks so much

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<style>
body {
    width:auto;
    font-family:Century Gothic, Arial, Verdana;
}

.wrapper {
    width:850px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

h4 {
    color: #db870a;
    font-size:16px;
}

.threeCol {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    width:30.50%;
    padding:30px 0px;
    text-align:justify;
}

/*Alterations*/
.noSpaces {
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.float {
    float:left;
}

.alignR {
    text-align:right;
}

.paddingR {
    padding:10px 30px 10px 0px;
}

.paddingL {
    padding:10px 0px 10px 30px;
}

.noPadding {
    padding: 10px 0px 10px 0px;
}


/*footer*/

#footer {
    display:block;
    background-color:#F60;

}


/*Other Articles*/

#otherArticles {
    font-size:12px;
}

</style>



<body>

<section id="otherArticles">
    <div class="wrapper">
    <article class="threeCol paddingR">
      <header><h4 class="noSpaces">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4></header>
      <p>Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus. Donec magna leo sapien augue tellus, phasellus erat, adipiscing lectus phasellus enim nulla, eu aliquam sodales</p>
    </article>

      <article class="threeCol paddingR">
      <header><h4 class="noSpaces">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4></header>
      <p>Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus. Donec magna1leo sapien augue tellus, phasellus erat, adipiscing lectus phasellus enim nulla, eu aliquam sodales</p>
    </article> 

        <article class="threeCol noPadding">
      <header><h4 class="noSpaces">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4></header>
      <p>Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus. Donec magna leo sapien augue tellus, phasellus erat, adipiscing lectus phasellus enim nulla, eu aliquam sodales</p>
    </article>
    </div
></section>

<br />

<footer id="footer">
<div class="wrapper">
    Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus. Donec magna leo sapien augue tellus, phasellus erat, adipiscin</div>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be HTML or XHTML? You have contradictory information in your source.

Comment: Im just new to html coding, Im trying to learn html5, can you identify the contradictory codes youve seen? This may hellp me improve my codes. Thanks.

Comment: You have a doctype for XHTML 1.0 transitional, but a http-equiv for HTML. Then you have some HTML5 elements (style without type, section, header etc) with a XHTML <br /> in between. You shouldn't mix those, it's better to choose one standard an then stick with it. Doctype for html5, etc.

Answer (score 2):

example

http://jsfiddle.net/amkrtchyan/DtgQR/

and when you write a html5 actualy a html5 doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`

Answer (score 0):

try changing

```
.wrapper {
    width:850px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-top:0px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}
```

to

```
#otherArticles{
width:850px;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is just a part of my page's code. Im using .wrapper several times to keep all the contents of my sections centrally aligned, so If I change it, it will affect other sections as well.

Comment: I want to keep the page width defined on the .wrapper class so whenever i want to change the width, I will just adjust it only from there.

Comment: why are you using .wrapper? I mean, why not delete the <section> id, and set the wrapper class to it: <section class="wrapper">

Comment: I changed it but still, the background color for div footer is still overlapping with #otherArticles :(

Comment: Id i assign the class wrapper to sections, it will wrap the background color im assigning to each section. I just want to wrap the contents of the section so it will be align center in the browser and the background color (outside the wrapper) will flow as long as the browser window's width.

Comment: Thanks Bernat however Im still having problems with this, 1st contents arent centred in the browser, 2nd the footer bgcolor is still affecting #otherArticles section (should be within #footer only). Appreciate your self maybe I have to resrtcuture my codes again. Thanks

Comment: please, read my last answer in this post, the one starting "More correct code... " http://stackoverflow.com/a/8723786/976655

Comment: I discovered the answer, I just need to apply floating:left to footer and otherArticles div :)

Comment: Yes but it didnt solve my problems, center align, background color overlapping

Comment: mmm I see the section aligned in the middle of the page, and background color not overlapped (tested safari, moz, chrome...)

Answer (score 0):

The problem with yours code is you are only setting color for footer.
Start your footer tag right after the body tag.
Only need to change starting of footer tag.

Answer (score 0):

More correct code... you should use an external CSS.

Untitled Document

```
<style>
body {
    width:auto;
    font-family:Century Gothic, Arial, Verdana;
}

section {
    width:850px;
    margin:0 auto;
    overflow:auto;
}

h4 {
    color: #db870a;
    font-size:16px;
}

article {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:30px 0px;
    text-align:justify;
    width:30%;
    margin-right:3%;
}

article.last{margin-right:0;}


/*footer*/

footer {
    display:block;
    background-color:#F60;
}


</style>



<body>

<section>
    <article >
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
      <p>Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus. Donec magna leo sapien augue tellus, phasellus erat, adipiscing lectus phasellus enim nulla, eu aliquam sodales</p>
    </article>

      <article>
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
      <p>Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus. Donec magna1leo sapien augue tellus, phasellus erat, adipiscing lectus phasellus enim nulla, eu aliquam sodales</p>
    </article> 

        <article class="last">
      <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h4>
      <p>Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus. Donec magna leo sapien augue tellus, phasellus erat, adipiscing lectus phasellus enim nulla, eu aliquam sodales</p>
    </article>
</section>

<footer>
    Rutrum vitae vestibulum condimentum metus. Donec magna leo sapien augue tellus, phasellus erat, adipiscin
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```